# Persist command executes before end of transaction

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, jta

The problem is following:

I have Generic Dao implementation and interface using EJB 3.1 which are extended by
specific implementations and business interfaces:

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T extends Rewritable<T>, PkType extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, PkType> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "tsm")
protected EntityManager em;

private final Class<T> clazz;

public GenericDaoImpl(final Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public void create(final T entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}

public T find(final PkType pk) {
    return (T) em.find(clazz, pk);
}

public void update(final PkType id, final T entity) {
    T oldEntity = em.find(clazz, id);
    oldEntity.overrideFrom(entity);
    em.merge(oldEntity);
}

public void update(final T entity) {
    em.merge(entity);
}

public void deleteById (final PkType id) {
    T entity = find(id);
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new TSMServiceException("Couldn't find " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " with id: " + id);
    }
    em.remove(entity);
}

public void delete (final T entity) {
    em.remove(entity);
}


/**
 *
 * @return returns true by default if entity has no specific relations
 */
public boolean hasNoRelations(PkType id) {
    return true;
}
```

}

The example implementation is:

```
@Stateless
```

public class CardProfileDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements CardProfileDao {

```
public CardProfileDaoImpl() {
    super(CardProfile.class);
}

//specific methods for current entity

@Override
public boolean hasNoRelations(Long id) {
    return em.createNamedQuery("CHECK_CARD_PROFILE_HAS_NO_RELATIONS")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .getResultList()
            .isEmpty();
}
```

}

Example business interface:

```
@Local
```

public interface CardProfileDao extends GenericDao {

```
// specific methods for this entity
```

}

But when I call the extended method in CMT transaction trying to persist new entity it is flushed before CMT transaction commits. Even more, it stays in database after transaction rollback.
As I understand inheritance of EJB container doesn't expose business interfaces extended from another class. So it can't join persist call to CMT transaction. So, the question is: Is there any way to execute methods from GenericDaoImpl in CMT transaction?

Comment: The problem was non-jta transaction type in my datasource configuration. One advice - always check configuration file given to you